# Audio Capture without overwriting the same file in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, audio, record

I've been reading on how to create an audio recording app here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

But the problem with it is that it will only save ONE audio file. Subsequent recordings will just overwrite that file over and over again. How do I fix it such that it will not overwrite the same file over and instead, create a new file each time I record?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you add some random string to the end of the file name? also you can make a sufix based on time, something like

```
public AudioRecordTest() {
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;

    mFileName += "/audiorecordtest_"+tsLong.toString()+".3gp";
}
```